# How do I hide the currency symbol and make the cell appear blank when the value is zero

Tags: excel-formula

I want to hide the accounting cell format currency symbol in column B, but as soon as there's data entered in column A which linked to column B, the currency symbol should appear automatically in column B.

I've tried the following:

- Format cells -->custom,
- Conditional formatting,
- IFBLANK formula,
- find/replace will not work for this,
- "show a zero in a cell that have zero value" tickbox is unticked

This is the current code I have in the cell that need to modify to appear blank when there's no data entered into column A.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$23;'Product List'!A1:C51;3;0);0)
```

the cell format is set to accounting

I expect the cell to be shown blank whereas it's currently showing the accounting cell format currency as R (I've managed to remove the dash).

Comment: custom number format of `_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);;_(@_)`

Comment: Could you please provide a working example by showing some (example) values in the relevant columns? Then the community will be able to help you better.

Comment: Scott, thank you so much, I used _(R* #,##00_);_(R* (#,##1,00);;_(@_) - and it worked!! Thank you thank you thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without an example of your data it's difficult, but you may check if changing your formula as follows would work:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$23;'Product List'!A1:C51;3;0);"")
```

Comment: Kaiser, I tried your formula and it interfered with the next column's formula, but thank you for your help!!

Comment: @SimoneDahkoul: You may change the next column's formula as a workaround. Cheers